# Which is the correct OAuth Flow for our use case?

Tags: docusignapi

First of all, I apologize for eventual noob questions, we are very new to the DocuSign API and are currently trying to wrap our heads around which is the most correct way of accessing the API.

I will start with an overview of our use case. We recently purchased a DocuSign prod. Account with an Organization enabled.

We have a Partner which uses a CMS Tooling which integrates with said DocuSign Account. This Tool allows for the Backoffice to create envelopes with documents inside and a url which leads to the signin ceremony through the Templates that we create inside the DocuSign Account. This url is afterwards send to the customer for them to sign the documents in the envelope. This Part is working and is currently being used.

Now what we want to achieve on our side, we have a **nextJS web-app** which allows the same customers (Which are the receivers of the created envelopes in the step above, same e-mail in both steps) to sign-in our web-app. We want to show the customer in a dashboard, if there are envelopes for him open that he can sign and if this is the case we want to show him the url which leads to the signin ceremony.

We were able to see that as soon as an envelope for a certain User is created through the CMS Tooling, we can see that envelope in our DocuSign Prod Account.
Now our thought process was, to show our customer his open envelopes, we just fetch all open envelopes in our DocuSign Account which match the customers E-Mail.

Is there anything wrong with this process or are we overlooking something?
And if it is okay to proceed this way which of the OAuth Flows is the correct one to use for this case?

From my understanding, the JWT Flow seems like the most reasonable one? Since the Customers that need to sign the documents, will not have any DocuSign accounts.

**What have you tried to solve the issue?**
*We tried using the direct API Access, which worked when set up correctly but since we didn't have a OAuth Flow in place the Access token is only valid for restricted amount of time obviously and has to be refreshed. Hence we have to think first about how to grant access correctly*

I would love to hear, what the right approach would be to achieve our desired result.

Once again Apologies for this kind of question, just trying to have a better understanding before we start building :)

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

According to the use case you mentioned using JWT Grant is fine as users of your integration will use a single system account to log in, you should use JWT Grant.

I would recommend going with the below link to know more regards different use cases and check the knowledge
https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/choose/
https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/oauth2-requirements-migration/